# Secret key with Devise and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Enviornment:

```
Rails 4
Devise
Windows 8.1
```

In devise.rb, I have the following:

```
  config.secret_key = 'mysecretkey' if Rails.env == 'development'
```

In secrets.yml, I have the following:

```
development:
  secret_key_base: mysecretkey
```

When I run the command rails s, and then localhost:3000, I get the following message:

```
Missing `secret_key_base` for 'development' environment, set this value in `config/secrets.yml`
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Is your yml file formatted correctly? Besides Yaml.load() you can try the solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287346/yaml-validation

Comment: kwalify says this is not a valid yml file. It says ERROR: [/development] 'development:' : unknown key. To be sure this is not caused by some weird formatting I introduced, I generated another app, added devise. I got the same error from the secrets.yml file Devise generated

Comment: Actually, kwalify does not like database.yml either, but rails has no problem with it

Comment: I was not using kwalify properly. http://instantyaml.appspot.com/ told me that there are no issues with the yml file

Comment: Do you mean you actually took 'mysecretkey' as rails secret_key_base? Rails expects a hexadecimal key by convention (eg. created with ```rake secret```); not sure though that this causes the problem, but it never harms to follow the conventions...

Comment: yes, this has nothing to do with the problem because I'm using the term mysecretkey for illustration purposes and not the actual key

Comment: Similar issues were reported at [devise issue 2554]( https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2554). But since you have Rails 4.1 (as I see you have a secrets.yml), you shouldn't have this issue. Are you sure you have [devise 3.2.3 at least](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/pull/2835)?

Comment: I had an issue with using the correct environment. My configuration settings were in a myname_dev environment

Answer (score 1):

I know this is too late for you, but I thought I would post an answer anyway, as it might be of some use to others.

It is well known to be bad practice to keep secret keys, API keys, etc., in your source code. The best way by far is to use environment variables, which you set outside of your application. You can use these variables by like:

```
  config.secret_key = ENV['DEVISE_SECRET']
```

Setting these variables in production manually can be tedious, but can also be made easy with gems, such as Figaro. These gems can also load these variables into your production environment for you. 
As a bonus, you can set any variable inside your application this way, such as the application name, mailer configuration, etc.

Comment: Not really. A Rails application's "public" area is "above" the web root. This means that if someone has enough privilege to have access above the web root document level, then they can read your environment variables. A better place to set these environment variables would be in the web server configuration file.